# Is it possible to browse the file system and upload the files on UIWebView in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload, uiwebview

In the web page, I have file upload widget. I need to show this web page on `UIWebView`. Is it possible to browse the file system and upload the pdf, doc, xls files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this answer was correct when written in 2012 and iOS 5 was current. iOS 6 introduced media uploads and iOS 8 allowed arbitrary file uploads.*

No is the short answer. iOS has no user accessible file-system.

At WWDC they announced the ability to upload pictures in iOS6 but there is no publically available information on how that works.

You could do it by interacting directly with the website using the lower level tools (NSURLConnection, etc) and creating your own "open" dialog.

Comment: try uploading the photo from safari in iPhone or iPad, they show option to choose from dropbox, pdfapp, and other.

Comment: @BlackTiger I updated my answer to reflect the current state.

Answer (score 1):

iOS grants the webView no means to browse the file system, so no you will not be able to use the normal upload mechanism in UIWebView

You will have to present some API to your web server that allows you to send images as POST

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be NO, since the webview runs in a different sandbox as compared to native applications.

Also there is no accessible file system mechanism like android for iOS.
Even native application have very limited file access pertaining to only their own and certain user directories like tmp, documents etc.